# I have installed fuzzywuzzy module but when i import it in jupyter notebook it give error no module found

Tags: python, pip, fuzzywuzzy

I have install fuzzywuzzy module and i can import in python shell when i import it in a jupyter notebook it gives error no module found.

````
>>> from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
>>>'''

```import pandas as pd
import json
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz```

```ModuleNotFoundError            
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a67086b59a14> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 import json
---> 3 from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fuzzywuzzy'```
````

Comment: Compare `sys.executable` and `sys.path` in shell vs notebook. Are you running the same interpreter, with same site packages location?

Comment: thanks Amadan You are right.shell Path =  "C:\\Users\\gopesh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python.exe", Notebook Path =  "['C:\\Users\\gopesh\\Anaconda3\\python37.zip',
  'C:\\Users\\gopesh\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\gopesh\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\gopesh\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\gopesh\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\gopesh\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\gopesh\\.ipython']" how do i install in my notebook interpreter....

Comment: Not sure, I never used Anaconda. I think Anaconda should have its own `pip` or `pip3` in its `bin` directory, try to find it and use that to install stuff.

Comment: Okay thanks again for your time..

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs a lot. I would recommend using a virtual environment and then doing `pip install fuzzywuzzy`
This is the most optimal and sure fire solution. The following are the instructions for creating and activating a virtual environment with venv:

## Mac OS & Linux: How To Setup Virtual Environment

1) After cloning the repo, `cd` into the repo and run the command: `python3 -m venv venv`

```
    This will create the virtual environment. Make sure to name it venv because the .gitignore file
    has been initialized to ignore it by default.
```

2) Activate the virtual environment by running the following command: `source venv/bin/activate`

3) At any moment, you can run `deactivate` to leave the virtual environment.

## Windows: How To Setup Virtual Environment

1) After cloning the repo, `cd` into the repo and run the command: `python -m venv venv`

```
    This will create the virtual environment. Make sure to name it venv because the .gitignore file
    has been initialized to ignore it by default.
```

2) Activate the virtual environment by running the following command: `venv\Scripts\activate.bat`

```
    To activate the virtual environment inside of a code editor's bash, run: venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
```

3) At any moment, you can run `deactivate` to leave the virtual environment.

Comment: If you could upvote your solution for others to see what worked, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Compare sys.executable and sys.path in shell vs notebook. Are you
>   running the same interpreter, with same site packages location? –
>   Amadan Jul 17 '19 at 5:32

This was the answer for me! I have copied the `sys.path` results from  my shell to assign `sys.path` within the notebook like this:

`sys.path = ['list-of-paths-from-my-shell']`

Then, it solved!

Bingo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it via Anaconda prompt