# can not import fuzzywuzzy module on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I am able to import fuzzywuzzy on command promt
but not able to import on jupyter notebook

I have even tried assigning sys.executable to my sys.path variable
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62419449/8031463

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
# sys.path.append(sys.executable)
sys.path = [sys.executable]
```

now here is the variable values

```
sys.executable
```

> 'c:\python3.6\python.exe'

```
sys.path
```

> ['c:\python3.6\python.exe']

Still i am getting no module error

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-e08dc57fd8ae> in <module>
      1 # unique_name_dict
----> 2 from fuzzywuzzy import process
      3 
      4 # word = "anuraag"
      5 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fuzzywuzzy'
```

Comment: are you able to import in cmd?

Comment: yes, i am able to import in cmd

Comment: well seems my sys.path doesn't have any python 3.7 directories (all python 3.6) and i found out my pip installs gets install into "c:\\python3.7\\lib\\site-packages". when i am appending the path to my sys.path i am able to import the module, but problem is how can i change the sys.executable path only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 2 paths in system environment, one for python 3.7 and one for 3.6

My jupyter notebook was running on python 3.7 and pip was installing all the packages to 3.6 by default.
I removed 3.6/bin folder from System environment it asked me to install fuzzywuzzy again and it is running perfect now